# "Most common “Y2K-style” bugs today" ... Keep or Delete?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

[This mildly interesting question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63131) has a respectable number of views, but it's clearly off-topic, it being a "make-list" question.

I've looked through the answers, and frankly I don't see a whole lot of value there, other than an opportunity to further bikeshed (as [occurred today](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/63390/1204)) and leave evidence that other similar questions can be asked here.

My choices are to delete it or leave it up with a historical lock.  Which should it be?

Comment: Currently only has 4720 views – not enough to warrant a historical lock IMO. Please purge this utterly off topic list from the face of the site; nothing of value would be lost.

Answer (score 6):

Burn it to the ground, please.

Comment: Agreed. With less than 5,000 views it's not worth keeping around.

Comment: Agreed and done.